# How to set up different graalvm-home and java-home in CI server to build native image

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Issue:
I want has two graalvm version in same CI server to build different quarkus version service project.

resason:
Because a few old service use quarkus-1.5.1 & graalvm-20.0.0 and I can't upgrade that version.
but I want use quarkus-1.13.1 & graalvm-21.0.0 in new service.

tried:
add `quarkus.native.graalvm-home` & `quarkus.native.java-home` in the pom.xml, setting graalvm path, but not working.

```
        <properties>
            <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            <quarkus.native.additional-build-args>${qaurkusNativeArgs}</quarkus.native.additional-build-args>
            <quarkus.native.graalvm-home>${quarkus.native.java-home}</quarkus.native.graalvm-home>
            <quarkus.native.java-home>${quarkus.native.java-home}</quarkus.native.java-home>
        </properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the GRAALVM_HOME environment variable when you run `mvn package -Dnative`.

So something like `GRAALVM_HOME=/some/path mvn package -Dnative` will make Quarkus use GraalVM from `/some/path`.

See https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.native.graalvm-home

Comment: thanks your response, I know change environment variable can make it, but I can't change it, because GRAALVM_HOME environment variable is global scope, change it will effect my old project(use graalvm-20.0.0). if I is wrong tell me pls

Comment: That is not correct, if you invoke the command the way I mentioned, the environment variable will only affect that command and will not be global

Comment: Thanks your response. Let me make sure this command snippet like you meaning?

Comment: ‘Export GRAALVM_HOME=$｛PathFor21.0.0} 
mvn package -Dnative‘

Comment: If this matches. I think I lost a few information to you, sorry. because mvn command will through agents OS account with daemon executed. so every export command will keep self. affect next mvn command.

Comment: No, you don't need `EXPORT ...`. Just copy and paste the command I added above. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942/141412 for details

Comment: I will try it and reply result, thanks you for patient.

Comment: You are right, this answer can fix a issue and don't effect other task. sorry response late  and thanks you.